how to reverse arabic text on java android studio?
this is the real text "السلام عليكم".
how can I make the output like this " ﻢﻜﻴﻠﻋ ﻡﻼﺴﻟﺍ"?
I tried used this code but the result not like what I want.
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("السلام عليكم");
buffer.reverse();
// The result "مكيلع مالسلا"

some games not support arabic language on the chat ... I want to build my own keyboard to write arabic verywell on those apps.

If you just want to write arabic well in your game then there are several Keyboard apps out there that can solve your problem, Such as:

Gboard

SwiftKey

Tamam Arabic Keyboard


If you still want to make your own app, you may consider using the ICU4J library: See Documentation Here

I tried this apps before ... not one of them works.

Ok, You can develop a better solution then. Read the documentation for ICU4J, Try to understand how it works. You might be able to make something brilliant here. Best of luck.

Not working. I want something like this site.   https://www.arabic-keyboard.org/photoshop-arabic/
